# Normalized/Unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I am confused with the following -

Do unit vectors and normalized vectors indicate the same thing?

If I have a vector, and if I divide it by the length of the vector, then what will we get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a unit vector in the direction of the original vector, meaning the vector has a magnitude of exactly one. That vector is said to have been *normalized*, and so sometimes it is referred to as a normalized vector.

So yes, unit vectors and normalized vectors are referring to the same concept.